# Avoid creating slf4j / logback loggers during default configuration phase on Websphere Liberty Profile

Tags: websphere, osgi, slf4j, websphere-liberty

When deploying an Enterprise Bundle Archive - EBA (containing several blueprint services) on Websphere Liberty Profile 8.5 I'm getting the following error messages on startup.

```
[23/10/12 8:07:32:725 CEST] 0000001d SystemErr R SLF4J: The following loggers will not work because they were created
[23/10/12 8:07:32:725 CEST] 0000001d SystemErr R SLF4J: during the default configuration phase of the underlying logging system.
[23/10/12 8:07:32:725 CEST] 0000001d SystemErr R SLF4J: See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#substituteLogger
[23/10/12 8:07:32:725 CEST] 0000001d SystemErr R SLF4J: some.package.containing.blueprint.service.MyService1
[23/10/12 8:07:32:725 CEST] 0000001d SystemErr R SLF4J: some.package.containing.blueprint.service.MyService2
[23/10/12 8:07:32:725 CEST] 0000001d SystemErr R SLF4J: some.package.containing.blueprint.service.MyService3
```

Although the EBA runs fine, no logging output is generated for all blueprint services contained in the EBA. (as they are replaced by no-op loggers)

The EBA deploys fine on Websphere 8.0 with the OSGI Enterprise Pack and logging works fine.

As far as logging is concerned, the EBA contains logback-core,logback-classic,slf4j-api and jcl-over-slf4j bundles.

Is there any way to get logging from these services without having to resort to the solutions outlined in http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#substituteLogger ? I would like to maintain the same EBA file that can be deployed on both the Websphere 8.0 and Websphere Liberty Profile 8.5